# Laravel public directory and storage directory

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I've been playing with this for a little while and cant seem to figure it out.

Here is the scenario. I'm looking to upload user files on a multi user website so they go into their respective folders. If i upload everything into the public directory (have already built functions) - everything works fine but its not going to be secure....however if i upload in to the storage directory i seem to have problems accessing it after the fact.

Can someone give me suggestion/point me in the right directing as to how I would go about accessing those files from the storage directory (download and show image preview with `<img src="" />`.

Any help appreciated! Using Laravel 5.1 on WAMP

P.S. I have read a tonn of articles online and here on stackoverflow to no avail...

Answer (score 1):

You can build your app around specific user folders inside storage or other folder(s) inaccessible from public. 
What you need to do next is create code in order to get those through php and display them in your application.

Check this laracast: https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=707-laravel-load-images-stored-outside-public-folder/0

It probably gives you an idea of what I am aiming at. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have code created that works great when all files sit inside the public directory. Ive looked at that page before and could get things working based on the suggestions there...

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

That's from Laravel.com

> The root directory of a fresh Laravel installation contains a variety of folders:
>
> The app directory, as you might expect, contains the core code of your
>   application. We'll explore this folder in more detail soon.
>
> The bootstrap folder contains a few files that bootstrap the framework
>   and configure autoloading, as well as a cache folder that contains a
>   few framework generated files for bootstrap performance optimization.
>
> The config directory, as the name implies, contains all of your
>   application's configuration files.
>
> The database folder contains your database migration and seeds. If you
>   wish, you may also use this folder to hold an SQLite database.
>
> The public directory contains the front controller and your assets
>   (images, JavaScript, CSS, etc.).
>
> The resources directory contains your views, raw assets (LESS, SASS,
>   CoffeeScript), and localization files.
>
> The storage directory contains compiled Blade templates, file based
>   sessions, file caches, and other files generated by the framework.
>   This folder is segregated into app, framework, and logs directories.
>   The app directory may be used to store any files utilized by your
>   application. The framework directory is used to store framework
>   generated files and caches. Finally, the logs directory contains your
>   application's log files.
>
> The tests directory contains your automated tests. An example PHPUnit
>   is provided out of the box.
>
> The vendor directory contains your Composer dependencies.

I hope I could answer your question
- John